# Why do I get "That's a miss"?

Tags: bug, new-nav

Lately I often get a "That's a miss"  when I click on the Questions button from my User-Page. The link is https://stackoverflow.com/?tagFilter=all and after pressing F5 I get the new questions. But why is it not working the first time?

Here is a screenshot:
[image: That's a miss]

Comment: So ... can we have "That's a Bingo!" when there *are* some results?

Comment: @Jongware Surely we should have "You've sunk my battleship!"